# Plex media server trustworthy?

Tags: plex

I just installed plex media server from the .deb package. As soon as it finished, I was able see my server's host name pop up on their web site at which point I could browse the entire file system! From their website! And oh yeah, it's not even using https.

Can anyone reassure me here? Is this ok?

Can I browse from an internal address instead? Is there some way to configure it so it can't phone home?

As is I don't think I want to keep this installed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you pay the $4.99 a month for plexpass? If you did that is why you can see your files from their website, they are not on their website and the website file is secure and encrypted, only you and the devices you allow access to can see your files. I have used plex for 2 years now with no issues. The correct address for plex is https://plex.tv/.  Can you supply the link to the web site you are using. Without paying the $4.99 plexmedia server acts like a dlna server and can be accessed from any computer in your network on an unsecure connection, as it is inside your firewall. BUt if you do not want to have access outside your own network, there are other blna/Upnp servers available like ps3mediaserver, umb, minidlna and several others.

Comment: No I haven't paid anything yet. Just trying it out to see if I like it. The url I'm using is http://app.plex.tv/web which resolves to an external address [52.49.86.135]

Comment: Not sure how to disable the auto url formatting but that link starts with http and not https.

Comment: when i clicked on your link it took me to an https web page, could be because I have a plex pass account. I think you get the http instead of the https because you don't have a plex pass account, I cannot be sure though because i keep going to an https even when u tyoe in the actual ip.